# Pandas DataFrame with dates far in the future

Tags: pandas, numpy, date, datetime64

I need to store some dates which are beyond the year-2262-limit. Since I only need dates and no times I thought I could get away with using `datetime.date`, which did work fine until I realised that later in the code there is some forced coercion of data types and I am unable to get around that. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["2022-12-31", "9999-12-31"]})
data["col2"] = data["col1"].apply(lambda x: datetime.date.fromisoformat(x))

# .... company code ....

# forced coercion
data.astype(dtype={"col1": str, "col2": datetime.date})
```

Among others, I have tried to supply the following types for the coercion of `col2`, to no avail.

- `datetime.date` -> dtype '<class 'datetime.date'>' not understood
- `np.datetime64` -> Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00

I have also tried to convert with `data["col2"].dt.to_pydatetime()`, which yields a "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" error.

I suppose what baffles me the most is that the `astype()` documentation says that one can supply any numpy or Python data type, and my understanding is that `datetime.date` *is* a Python data type. So why wouldn't `astype()` know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's not exactly true that you can supply any valid Python type (and I don't think the docs claim this). I guess what is meant is that you can supply both numpy types as well as the extended dtypes added by Pandas (or other libraries), listed in [this table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/basics.html#dtypes).

In your case you might want to use a Period, which is one of the suggestions in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans) for this case. So it would be something like:

```
def convert_to_date(x):
    y, m, d = [int(n) for n in x.split('-')]
    return pd.Period(year=y, month=m, day=d, freq="D")

data = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["2022-12-31", "9999-12-31"]})
data["col2"] = data.col1.apply(convert_to_date)

data.astype(dtype={"col1": str, "col2": 'period[D]'})
```

This way you can use vectorised operations (ie it's not an object dtype like you had with `datetime.date`), but you can also store dates outside the bounds of pandas `datetime64[ns]` dtype.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the links. I didn't know that "Period" existed and will try to work out a solution.